# How to read streaming dataset once and output to multiple sinks?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have Spark Structured Streaming Job that reads from S3, transforms the data and then store it to one S3 sink and one Elasticsearch sink.

Currently, I am doing `readStream` once and then    `writeStream.format("").start()` twice. When doing so it seems that Spark read the data twice from S3 source, once per each sink.

Is there a more efficient way to write to multiple sinks in the same pipeline?

Answer (score 14):

> Currently, I am doing readStream once and then twice writeStream.format("").start().

You actually create two separate streaming queries. The `load`-part is to describe the first (and only) streaming source. That does nothing execution-wise.

> When doing so it seems that Spark read the data twice from S3 source, per each sink.

That's the most correct way to describe how Spark Structured Streaming's queries work. The number of sinks correspond to the number of queries because one streaming query can have exactly one streaming sink (see [StreamExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/StreamExecution.scala#L65) that sits behind any streaming query).

You can also check the number of threads (using `jconsole` or similar) as Structured Streaming uses one `microBatchThread` thread per streaming query (see [StreamExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/StreamExecution.scala#L218)).

> Is there a more efficient way to write to multiple sinks in the same pipeline?

It is **not** possible in the current design of Spark Structured Streaming.

Comment: Is this last part (still) true? in the 2.4.3 latest and earlier versions I see that from aDF writeStream can be called twice, for example. May be the earlier implementation.

Comment: @thebluephantom Do you have a code to show your point? Whatever I can come up with shows that it's impossible still. Help much appreciated. Use gist.github.com.

Comment: 2.4.3 Struct Streaming Guide // ========== DF with aggregation ==========
val aggDF = df.groupBy("device").count()

// Print updated aggregations to console
aggDF
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()

// Have all the aggregates in an in-memory table
aggDF
  .writeStream
  .queryName("aggregates")    // this query name will be the table name
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("memory")
  .start()

spark.sql("select * from aggregates").show()

Comment: Above Section Using Foreach and ForeachBatch; I may have misinterpreted this, so that is why I am asking

Comment: Very interested as then in this example seems to me the same Data Pipeline.

Comment: Whatever happens after `writeStream` defines a separate streaming sink which basically defines separate streaming query (since a streaming query can have one streaming sink only).

Comment: What say the source was kafka?

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is `cache()` the data after reading once and use the data multiple times. I do not believe Spark Structured Streaming currently supports caching (see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20927)), however you can use Spark Streaming. It's a lower level API compared to Structured Streaming (using an underlying RDD as compared to Dataframe/Dataset). From the Spark Streaming [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#caching--persistence):

> Similar to RDDs, DStreams also allow developers to persist the stream’s data in memory. That is, using the persist() method on a DStream will automatically persist every RDD of that DStream in memory. This is useful if the data in the DStream will be computed multiple times (e.g., multiple operations on the same data).

Using the Spark Streaming API you can use `Dstream.cache()` on the data. This marks the underlying RDDs as cached which should prevent a second read. Spark Streaming will unpersist the RDDs automatically after a timeout, you can control the behavior with the `spark.cleaner.ttl` setting. Note that the default value is infinite which I would not recommend in a production setting.

Instead of using `Dstream.cache()` where you need to wait for the `spark.cleaner.ttl` timeout, there is another way to cache the data. It's possible to use `foreachRDD` to directly access the underlying RDDs. Here the RDDs can be uncached *directly* after usage.

```
dstream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
  rdd.cache()
  // perform any transormations, etc. 
  rdd.saveAs(...)
  rdd.unpersist(true)
}
```

Comment: _"This marks the underlying RDDs as cached which should prevent a second read."_ <-- only when the RDD is shared between Spark jobs. What's the use case for it in Spark Streaming?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I would say this situation (question) would be a potential use case? See my edit.

Comment: I still don't know how to do it in Spark Streaming :( Care to share a code to demo it? (that would make the answer feature-complete and deserve my upvote though it's about Spark Streaming :))

Comment: @JacekLaskowski You can simply add `.cache()` to a `DStream` (a continuous sequence of RDDs). However, in some cases it is more efficient to access the RDDs themselves, added some information and a small example to illustrate.

Comment: Using `foreachRDD` is **not** `DStream.cache`, is it? I'm asking about a use case for the latter, i.e. `DStream.cache` and reusing the cached RDDs.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Correct, it's not. Which one to use (directly use `cache` or `foreachRDD` with cache) for best performance depends on the use case. As for you asking for a use case for `DStream.cache()`, isn't this question itself such a use case (as I stated above)? Caching a `DStream` is a good idea in those cases where you would want to cache a normal RDD; where you have multiple actions on the same RDD and do not want to re-read it/re-perform transformations on it.

Answer (score 4):

I am also looking for solution of this problem .  I want to write some records of dataframe in sink1 while other records in sink2 (depending upon some condition, without reading the same data twice in 2 streaming queries). Currently it does not seem possible as per current implementation ( createSink() method in DataSource.scala provides support for a single sink).

However, In Spark 2.4.0 there is a new api coming: foreachBatch() which will give handle to a dataframe microbatch which can be used to cache the dataframe, write to different sinks or processing multiple times before uncaching aagin. Something like this:

```
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  batchDF.cache()
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 1
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 2
  batchDF.uncache()
}
```

right now this feature available in databricks runtime : https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/foreach.html#reuse-existing-batch-data-sources-with-foreachbatch

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Below code is written in Scala V2.13.3.

```
package com.spark.structured.stream.multisink

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger.ProcessingTime
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

object MultipleStreamingSink extends App {

val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.master("local[*]")
.getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val csvSchema = new StructType()
.add("name", "string").add("age", "integer").add("num","integer").add("date", "string")

val sample = spark.readStream
.schema(csvSchema)
.format("csv")
.options(Map("inferSchema" ->"true", "delimiter"->",", "header"->"true"))
.load("path/to/input/dir")


val sample1 = sample.withColumn("datetime",col("date").cast(TimestampType)).drop("date")

val sampleAgg1 = sample1.withWatermark("datetime", "10 minutes")
.groupBy(window($"datetime", "5 minutes", "5 minutes"), col("name"))
.agg(count("age").alias("age_count"))

val sampleAgg2 = sample1.withWatermark("datetime", "10 minutes")
.groupBy(window($"datetime", "5 minutes", "5 minutes"), col("age"))
.agg(count("name").alias("name_count"))


// I have used console to stream the output, use your sinks accordingly 
val sink1 = sampleAgg1
.withColumn("window_start_time", col("window.start"))
.withColumn("window_end_time", col("window.end"))
.drop("window")
.writeStream
.queryName("count by name")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/1")
.outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("60 seconds"))
.format("console")
.option("numRows", 100)
.option("truncate", false)
.start()

val sink2 = sampleAgg2
.withColumn("window_start_time", col("window.start"))
.withColumn("window_end_time", col("window.end"))
.drop("window")
.writeStream
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/2")
.queryName("count by age")
.outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("60 seconds"))
.format("console")
.option("numRows", 100)
.option("truncate", false)
.start()

sink1.awaitTermination()
sink2.awaitTermination()
```

This is my sample csv file content,

```
name,age,num,date
abc,28,123,2021-06-01T07:15:00
def,27,124,2021-06-01T08:16:00
abc,28,125,2021-06-01T07:15:00
ghi,28,126,2021-06-01T07:17:00
```

Comment: Are you sure this code doesn't read the `csv` file twice? There is nothing that indicates any kind of caching or such feature that would help with multiple reading of the same file.